# Rails 4 set config.time_zone through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, timezone, config

In my app, I've created a `/configure` view that allows `admin` users to adjust some of the features and records.

One of the things I'd like them to able to customize is the `config.time_zone` setting through a select field.

I've been trying to use the [`time_zone_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select) tag, but with no success.

Is it even possible to change the `config.time_zone` variable stored in the `application.rb` file through a view / form?

Comment: I would think changes to `config.time_zone` would require a restart of the rails process, however you can save the configured setting in the database and then change `Time.zone` for each request in a before or around filter of the application_controller - you might find this blog post helpful: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: This is great. I wound up implementing this by `user` as the blog and [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised) recommended. If you make this an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: done: added comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think changes to `config.time_zone` would require a restart of the rails process, however you can save the configured setting in the database and then change `Time.zone` for each request in a before or around filter of the application_controller

you might find this blog post helpful: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/